# Saving a CNPostalAddress in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, cnpostaladdress

I have this code:

```
CNMutablePostalAddress *postalAddress = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
[postalAddress setCity:@"City"];

CNLabeledValue *city = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNPostalAddressCityKey value:postalAddress.city];

NSArray<CNLabeledValue<CNMutablePostalAddress *> *> *postalAddresses = @[city];

contact.postalAddresses = @[postalAddresses];
```

I don't know how I can do this conversion, because I need to pass an array to `contact.postalAddress` in the code. I have tried everything possible, but got nothing.

This code give me this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyInvalidTypeException', reason: 'Labeled value (
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x12d5a14c0: identifier=080A5D1B-1F2D-4EE2-AB6F-BFAD523DA1C9, label=city, value=City>") has incorrect type __NSArrayI for key postalAddresses. It should be CNLabeledValue.'
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What conversion do you want to do? Saving and converting are different things, please correct either title or story.

Comment: I need to save the "city" in "contact.postalAddresses", but I need to do the conversion before or the application will crash with the exception. @meaning-matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a new postal address and adds it to the `contact`. This is what you want, right?

```
CNMutablePostalAddress *postalAddress = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
postalAddress.city = @"City";

CNLabeledValue *labeledValue = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:address];
contact.postalAddresses = @[labeledValue];
```

Comment: Yees! Thank you so much! :) @meaning-matters

Comment: @David Glad to help!  You can also vote up ^ this answer, in case you didn't know ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct implementation.

```
CNMutablePostalAddress *postalAddress = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
postalAddress.street = @"1 Market Street";
postalAddress.city = @"Sydney";
postalAddress.postalCode = @"2000";
postalAddress.state = @"NSW";
CNLabeledValue *address = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:postalAddress];
contact.postalAddresses = @[address];
```